# Need regex for accepting only positive whole number without preceding zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not good in Regex and now I am in need of one Regex which accepts only positive whole numbers (like 1,2,3 ... n).

Invalid values are

```
01, 001, 0, 1.0, -1,-1.0,-01.
```

Tried this, but its accepting "01" which is not valid in my case.

```
/[1-9][0-9]*/
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Its not duplicate. tried those things. Its accepting "01". I told already, "01" is not valid in my case.

Comment: try this: `^(?![\-0].*$)[\d]+`

Comment: but you are wrong, the linked answer will work as well and is much simpler than mine

Comment: basically your expression is only missing a `^` at the beginning. This indicates that the number must start with 1-9